# How to work out which of these two equations is larger?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two equations:

1. $x = 2^n (p+i)^{3n}$
2. $x = 14^n p^{3n} $

Here $n$, $p$, and $i$ are all integers $\geq0$.

I worked out (using a spreadsheet) that if $i > 1$ then the value of x in expression 1 is larger than the value of x in expression 2.

How can I show this mathematically?

Comment: Is $n, p, i$ a natural number, an integer or any real number?

Comment: $n$ is an integer. I will edit the question.

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 the value of x is larger. What is the correct way to phrase this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the two equations.
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\frac{x_1}{x_2}&=\frac{2^n(p+i)^{3n}}{14^n p^{3n}}\\
&=\frac{2^n(p+i)^{3n}}{(2\cdot7)^n p^{3n}}\\
&=\frac{\cancel{2^n}(p+i)^{3n}}{\cancel{2^n} 7^n p^{3n}}\\
&=\frac{1}{7^n}\left(\frac{p+i}{p}\right)^{3n}\\
&=\left(\frac{\left(\frac{p+i}{p}\right)^{3}}{7}\right)^n\\
&=\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac{i}{p}\right)^{3}}{7}\right)^n\\
\end{align}
$x_1>x_2$ if the value of $i,p,n$ are greater than zero and $i\ge p$. For instance, let $i=p=1$, you get
\begin{equation}
\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{1}\right)^{3}}{7}\right)^n=\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)^n\qquad\text{hence } x_1>x_2
\end{equation}

Comment: Yay! Thank you @Sorin!

Comment: Thank you! But what is the rule for (p+1)/p = 1 + (i/p)?

Comment: @S0rin Using distributive law of division: $\cfrac{p+i}{p}=\cfrac{p}{p}+\cfrac{i}{p}=1+\cfrac{i}{p}$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome @S0rin!

Comment: Is it the same rule to derive $\frac{1}{7^n}\left(\frac{p+i}{p}\right)^{3n}$

from $\frac{(p+i)^{3n}}{7^n p^{3n}}$ ?

Comment: @S0rin No. It's different. I just split them. It's kind like $abc$, you can do it like this $(ab)c$, $a(bc)$ or $(ac)b$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because it's not true in general.
if $u_n$ is 1., and $v_n$ is 2., then

$${u_n \over v_n} = {1 \over 7}^n (({p+i \over p})^3)^n$$

So it all comes down to knowing if

$$({p+i \over p})^3 > 7$$